# How to develop an edit option on hover of a div

Tags: javascript, css, model-view-controller

I'm trying to use the hover option to display an small edit image/button in the top right hand corner of a div. I have a dynamically created table of x by y number of cells. What I would like to do is have a tiny edit button in the top right hand corner that allows me to click on that button and bring up a popup window.

Something similar to the following:
[image: twitter hover]

where the user is presented with options over the div on hover. 
Would this need to be done in javascript or css? I am using javascript to create the table as follows:

```
    var col = document.getElementById("NoColumns").value;
    var row = document.getElementById("NoRows").value;
    if (col > 0 || row > 0) {
        $("#tblDash").show();
        $("#NumberOfColumns").val(col);
        $("#NumberOfRows").val(row);

        for (var x = 1; x <= row; x++)
        {
            tr = document.createElement('tr');
            document.getElementById('table').appendChild(tr);

            for (var i = 1; i <= col; i++) {
                var td = document.createElement('td');
                td.className = "drop";
                td.id = x + ', ' + i;
                td.setAttribute('onclick', 'clicked(this);')
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
                tr.appendChild(td);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Display the button when you hover on the container, else keep it hidden via CSS?

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: yellowgreen;
  position: relative;
}

.container:hover > .btn {
  display: block;
}

.btn {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="btn">Edit</btn>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me, except position for the btn needed to be relative and not absolute, otherwise nothing would show even if I hovered.

Comment: Just an additional question regarding this thread - I have an onclick function on the td that the button is within ` td.setAttribute('onclick', 'clicked(this);')`. When I click the button, the onclick of the td is fired. How do I avoid the td's onclick call on the button click?

Answer (score 0):

It will be done with CSS. add "button" class to these three buttons and use the css below.

```
.button {
    display: none;
}

div:hover + .button, .button:hover {
    display: inline-block;
}
```